# How to produce dot between quantifiers

Tags: symbols

My professor uses dots between quantifiers, e.g.,

[image]

And my textbook has them like this:

[image]

I tried Detexify on this, but it didn't work... does anyone know how to produce either of these bold dots?

Comment: [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive) might help.

Comment: @Derek I've looked there; maybe it's in a section one wouldn't expect?

Comment: After looking there myself, the best I could come up with was `\blacksquare` (Table 202), which is too large.

Answer (score 8):

## First case: square dot with equal spaceing

The first case is probably `\centerdot` of package `amssymb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
  \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \centerdot \forall m \in \mathbb{N} \centerdot m < n
\]
\let\oldcenterdot\centerdot
\renewcommand*{\centerdot}{\mathrel{\oldcenterdot}}%
\[
  \exists\,n \in \mathbb{N} \centerdot \forall\,m \in \mathbb{N} \centerdot m < n
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result first case]

`\centerdot` is a binary operator. In the image in the question, the spacing seems to be slightly larger. Therefore the second line uses

- the spacing of a relational operator by redefining `\centerdot` and
- adds a thin space after the quantifiers.

## Second case: round dot with asymmetrical spacing

In the second case a bold version of the dot could be used. The spacing seems to be a little special, the example uses

- half of a thin space at the left and
- a thick space at the right (as for relational operators).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand*{\anddot}{%
  \mathclose{}%
  \nonscript\mskip.5\thinmuskip
  \boldsymbol{.}%
  \;%
  \mathopen{}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
  \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \anddot x^2 \ge 0
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result second case]

Comment: this does look like `\centerdot` to me.  (i'd like to point out that it was originally intended to be a bold version of `\cdot`, but something went awry, and it's much too late to change anything now.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the clarification. I was wondering about the name part "center" of `\centerdot`.

Answer (score 5):

The first seem more square than round, which you can generate using `\rule{<width>}{<height>}`. The second seems like an enlarged `.`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}
\newcommand{\dsepA}{\mathrel{\rule{.25ex}{.25ex}}}
\newcommand{\dsepB}{\mathbin{\scalebox{1.5}{.}}}
\begin{document}
$\exists n \in \mathbb{N} \dsepA \forall m \in \mathbb{N} \dsepA m < n$

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \dsepB x^2 \geq 0$
\end{document}
```

The first is modelled as a relation (`\mathrel`), although it probably doesn't relate the respective quantifiers. The second uses `\mathbin`.

Comment: It could be considered as an “and” operator, so `\mathbin` may be… or may be its own spacing without relying on math atoms.